# What does force_reload mean?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

In ActiveRecord, when an object is given a `belongs_to` class method, it gains access to the `#other` instance method, where `other` is the classname that was passed to `belongs_to`. In the documentation at http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html, though, this method is listed as `other(force_reload=false)`. What is the force_reload option, and what happens if I set it to true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's option to force association to reload.

Example, you have two model `User` and `Address`:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :address
end

class Address < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end
```

And you have an address: `address = Address.first`

Instead of this:

```
user = address.user
user.reload
```

You can use:

```
user = address.user(force_reload: true)
```

It will fetch data of `user` from database (which makes an SQL query), not in memory.